# Creat procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, procedure

I was learning sql from w3schools.Here is given simple mysql procedure but somehow I couldn't to write down this procedure I'm new in sql please could you provide me with feedback.
[image]

```
  DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllAgents
BEGIN
SELECT
 * FROM agents
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to execute this procedure I'm keep going to get following error

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'begin select  * from agents  end' at line 2

Comment: The GO and EXEC statements suggest to me that this is a sqlserver procedure and it won't work in mariadb. Do you have a hyperlink to the w3schools page?

Comment: yes of course https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp

Comment: The header on this page states it is for sqlserver. Mariadb/mysql is a different dialect  of sql to sqlserver if you are using mariadb you should not try learning from sqlserver or you should install sqlserver.https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bellow

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllCustomers

BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Customers

END //
DELIMITER ;



  call SelectAllCustomers
```

if you use mariyaDB

```
CREATE procedure selectAllCustomers()
SELECT * FROM customer
```

to execute

```
call selectAllCustomers
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
select
 * from agents
 end' at line 2

Comment: Every statement must be terminated , the select needs a ; AND you need to specify parameters even if you don't don't want  any with ()

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich are u using MariyaDB

Comment: @Indrakumara yes sir

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich Try Now

Comment: great Thanks sir

Comment: @Indrakumara - Edit your answer to reflect the issues brought up in the Comments.